# iOS - Present View controller immediately after dismissing an other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

I have three View Controller VC1,VC2 and VC3.

VC2 is of a 3rd party library and it is presented on VC1.

Then VC2 dismissed itself and send a callback to VC1 and VC1 try to present VC3 on itself but failed.

Is there some way to present VC3 immediately after dismissing VC2 ?

```
-(void)onDismisLoginVC{

    MessageVC *messageVC = [[MessageVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Unfortunately I can not use `^completion` block of dismissing presented viewcontroller in VC2 because I am just receiving a callback to this method and can't edit code of VC2.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: If you do not show us code and do not tell us what is "your case" like, which iOS you support, than you can't expect help, I think.

Comment: Why not present vc3 without dismissing and then dismiss both at the end...

Comment: VC2 dismissed it self, its not in my control.

Comment: Have VC2 call the delegate in the completion block when it dismisses itself.

Comment: There are a million ways to do this.  Completion block, delegate methods, NSNotificationCenter, etc., but no one can help you until you start telling us WHY specifically these things aren't working.  Now that you've edited your code into the question, are you certain the method is being called?

Comment: I have made an edit. Please check it.

Comment: How come you can't edit the code in VC2?  And again, are you certain the method you've posted is being called?

Comment: Yes it is called, I have checked by adding breakpoint.

Comment: 1. Please check, if `self.navigationController` is `nil`. 2. If its not nil, tell us, if the VC is pushed, if you set `animated` to `NO`. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know we all always put `nil` for the completion block... but it actually does have some use.  I assure you.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //code to be executed with the dismissal is completed
    // for example, presenting a vc or performing a segue
    }];
```

Comment: This solution defiantly worked for me a while ago, but in current situation I can not used completion block.

Comment: I don't know how to help you if you share no code, and then claim that the completion block won't work and won't explain why.

Answer (score 6):

This is the one I use to dismiss a Facebook login view controller.

```
UIViewController *theTrick = self.presentingViewController;
UIViewController *toPresent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"toPresentViewController"];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [theTrick presentViewController:toPresent animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for help guys. Adding a little bit delay before presenting VC3 solved the problem.

```
-(void)onDismisLoginVC{

[self performSelector:@selector(presentMessageVC) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

}

-(void)presentMessageVC
{

MessageVC *messageVC = [[MessageVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is bad if you're not using it for really specific cases (you're question is not that case).